# StorCli not seeing IcyDock drives trough RAID controller

Tags: raid, broadcom, storcli

I am trying to use my drives through a MegaRAID 9540-8i, I am using an official cable from Broadcom for said controller (Broadcom 05-60002-00 Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)-cable)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBWi9.png]

and using this ( https://global.icydock.com/product_232.html ) icydock storage system.

cable is correctly installed.

firmware latest for the RAID controller.

[image: storcli64]

could anyone help me detect my drives?